# Eclipse import org.jgrapht cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, unresolved-external

I have a project in Java in Eclipse (found it on www) but after importing it as a file system, i get continusly the unresolved errors for those two imports:
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;

Any idea how to pass this isue and run it;

Comment: Clearly the project is expecting to use the JGraphT library; is that JAR included in the project contents, or perhaps is the project using Maven or Gradle to mange dependencies?

Comment: No, is not using maven.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download jgrapht.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjgraphtjar.htm) and add it in your project library.

Comment: After insertingit, continues to searhing it from org and stays the error. Should i remove the line with importorg... From the start?

Comment: Finaly, i insert as a clear new wproject, added the jgrapht.jar to library and works!!